# Integrate $\int \frac{1}{x^3}e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, self-learning

$$\int \frac{1}{x^3}e^{-x^2}dx$$

What I did?

put $1/x^2 = t; $

then $\int \frac{1}{x^3}e^{-x^2}dx$ will trasform into $\frac{-1}{2}\int e^{-1/t}dt$

I don't understand how to proceed there after.

**EDIT:**

This problem was given to me by my student. I inquired her, she corrected the problem as $\int \frac{1}{x^3}e^{-x^{-2}}dx$  that makes the problem very simple. Sorry for troubling you all.

Comment: I am surprised this would be homework. There is no elementary function whose derivative is $\frac{1}{x^3}e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: There is alos "Self-Learning" Tag. Its not a problem given to me in a class or something. I'm doing problems by self from a 1st year Bachelor's level book.

Comment: You would have to quote the problem exactly. *Numerical* evaluation of related definite integrals would be possible, or a Fundamental Theorem of Calculus question, but not an indefinite integral question, unless they first define the exponential integral function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try $u=x^2,\ du=2xdx$.  Then $\int \frac{1}{x^3}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac 12\int\frac 1{u^2}e^{-u}du$, which can be integrated by parts using the [Exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), but not using more elementary functions.